# Can we add public group to unmanaged/managed package?

Tags: salesforce, packaging, salesforce-lightning

I have created a public group to give access on report folder. Now i created unmanaged package and added all the components but not able to add public group to the package.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Public groups and queues can't be packaged. You'll have to write some install steps / release notes to admins that install the app, suggesting how they can configure the security.

List of packageable items is in https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/226/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_packaging_guide.pdf pages 24-32 or

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_unmanaged_components.htm